# Presto Unnest varchar array field

Tags: sql, arrays, presto, unnest

I am new to Presto and to data stored as arrays. I have a table which has a varchar column containing data that looks like this:

[image: Table]

i.e. an application can be declined for multiple reasons. I need to show "how many applications were declined for what reasons" i.e output should look like this :

[image: output]

I have tried unnest but get "Cannot unnest type: varchar"

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(decline_reasons) AS t(value)
```

Also tried cast as array but get "Unknown type: array"

```sql
SELECT cast(json_parse(decline_reasons) as array) 
FROM table
```

Would appreciate tips / guidance.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast the data to array by

```sql
cast(json_parse(decline_reasons) as array<varchar>)
```

Then, you will be able to use `UNNEST` for the array result.

https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse

Comment: @reachbgk It means the actual data is different from your example or the version is old. Could you try the latest version https://prestosql.io/download.html?

Answer (score -1):

Figured out how to array and make rows out of it. Counting will be the easy part now

```
SELECT split_b 
FROM table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(replace(replace(replace(json_format(cast(split(replace(replace(replace(regexp_replace(decline_reasons,'\s'),'"',''),'[',''),']',''),',') as json)),'[',''),']',''),'"',''),',')) AS t (split_b)
```